# Bootstrap row does not fill width of screen, when hidden/displayed based on a breakpoint

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap container-fluid, which contains a row. The row should display only on screens larger than 'medium'. To achieve that, I've added 'd-none d-md-block' to the row class. This works, in terms of appearing/hiding, but all of the columns in it fill the width of the screen, and are therefore stacked vertically, when they should be horizontal.
Strangely, if I remove the d-none d-md-block classes, the columns display horizontally as expected. Code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row d-none d-md-block">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="menu_circle">Link 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="menu_circle">Link 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="menu_circle">Link 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="menu_circle">Link 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/139426/
(you may have to make the output window slightly bigger to trigger the visibility).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `d-md-block` you can use [`d-md-flex`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/#enable-flex-behaviors):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row d-none d-md-flex">
        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="menu_circle">Link 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="menu_circle">Link 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="menu_circle">Link 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
            <div class="menu_circle">Link 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap 4.1 is using flexbox to format the rows and columns of the grid system. By using `d-md-block` you remove (overwrite) the flex rules on the `row`, so the columns (`col-*`) breaks too.